# ExecJS::RuntimeError Errors when creating new Ruby on Rails. Crash after controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, execjs

I'm having an issue creating a new Rails app. I created a test to and copied my command prompt to let you see what happens.

The story is this: I can make the app, boot up the test server, and get the page. I can then generate a controller for Pages with a page inside called home. Its created, I boot the server back. Now, this is where the crashes and errors happen.

In my URL bar, the second I type "/p" for Pages the error messages generate in my prompt.

```
    'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails>rails new testing_errors
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.3
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.3
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.3
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.3
Using activemodel 4.2.3
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.7.7
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using byebug 5.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.3
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.1
Using jquery-rails 4.0.4
Using sprockets 3.3.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
Using rails 4.2.3
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass 3.4.16
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using tzinfo-data 1.2015.6
Using uglifier 2.7.1
Using web-console 2.2.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails>cd testing_errors

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>rails generate controller Pages home
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
       route  get 'pages/home'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/pages
      create    app/views/pages/home.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/pages.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>rails s
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-08-12 15:23:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-08-12 15:23:50] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-08-12 15:23:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9420 port=3000


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-08-12 15:23:52 -0400
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 16.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/pages/home" for ::1 at 2015-08-12 15:23:57 -0400
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 479ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (["ok"]):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>TestingErrors</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___495674848_49918752'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (46.9ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (36.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (82.8ms)
[2015-08-12 15:24:02] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2015-08-12 15:24:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>
```

I am running Windows 10 Pro and here is my Ruby, Rails, and Node info.

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>


C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>node -v
v0.12.7

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>rails -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.2.3

C:\Users\arlic\Desktop\Rails\testing_errors>
```

Here is the Message I get as well

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G4fh.png

Answer (score 0):

Quick work around could be:
Removing `//= require_tree .` from `application.js`

Then, restart the server and try again.

#### Update:

Navigate to `\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb`

Change line 6 from:

```
'<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>'
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'defaults', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

See if that works!

Comment: No dice. I did the edit people posted about changing the UTC-16 to 8 as well.

Comment: @Atnevon look at my edit and try this out. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be actually with a stray variable inside of my registry. For my class we setup sublime text 2 to have a shortcut to open directly in command prompt (it does it automatically on Macs)

Here is the value I got rid of, and also reinstalled node.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmC63.jpg